# motherboard, network cards, ports, printer detection tools for .net

Tags: asp.net, winapi, wmi

does anybody  have a hardware detection api for .net?

Comment: Something like the System.Management namespace?
Or are you looking for some clever wrapper for this namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management%28VS.80%29.aspx) namespace. You probably want to start by looking at [`ManagementQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementquery%28VS.80%29.aspx) [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher%28VS.80%29.aspx).